# Why isnt there an Ubuntu release name starting with C (and A)

Tags: release-management

Its Breezy Badger then Dapper Drake. Where are Clumsy Chameleon and Awesome Antelope?

Comment: I actually thought the reasons were more along the lines of not having anything to do with some "body parts" when Ubuntu OS was starting. I think people are more matured now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first two release was named randomly and came from a joke. And from the third release they decided to use alphabetical order in release names. This is documented very well in the [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames)

From Mark Shuttleworth's writing, I'm quoting this from the wiki page:

> Many sensible people have wondered why we chose this naming scheme. It came about as a joke on a ferry between Circular Quay and somewhere else, in Sydney, Australia:
>
> lifeless: how long before we make a first release?
>      sabdfl: it would need to be punchy. six months max.
>      lifeless: six months! thats not a lot of time for polish.
>      sabdfl: so we'll have to nickname it the warty warthog release
>
> <sup>lifeless is Robert Collins. sabdfl is Mark Shuttleworth.</sup>

So, the naming convention or policy wasn't fixed before the first release as you might have been assuming. That convention is later introduced and of course it is one of the greatest feature of Ubuntu OS.

- [Read the history in Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#History)
- [Also read all the *dashing* naming suggestion given for upcoming releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#Code_Name_Suggestions)

Though they decided to use alphabetical name after Breezy, they also decided that they might avoid some letters. I think that is why there isn't a C name after Breezy. The [relevant part form the Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#History) is

> We might skip a few letters, and we'll have to wrap eventually

And from 17.10 the release names will be wrapped up and will be restarted with **A**. So, don't forget to suggest your awesome names.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently versions that were released after 6.06 were alphabetically incremented in their alliterative letter. So chances are good that there will be an A... A... coming with version 17.10 and a C... C... coming with version 18.10. For the release history with numbering and names, see below or [the List of Releases on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

```
 4.10 Warty Warthog     
 5.04 Hoary Hedgehog    
 5.10 Breezy Badger
 ...    
 6.06 Dapper Drake      
 6.10 Edgy Eft      
 7.04 Feisty Fawn       
 7.10 Gutsy Gibbon      
 8.04 Hardy Heron       
 8.10 Intrepid Ibex     
 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope  
 9.10 Karmic Koala      
10.04 Lucid Lynx        
10.10 Maverick Meerkat  
11.04 Natty Narwhal
11.10 Oneiric Ocelot
12.04 Precise Pangolin
12.10 Quantal Quetzal
13.04 Raring Ringtail
13.10 Saucy Salamander
14.04 Trusty Tahr
14.10 Utopic Unicorn
15.04 Vivid Vervet
15.10 Wily Werewolf
16.04 Xenial Xerus
16.10 Yakkety Yak
17.04 Zesty Zapus
17.10 Artful Aardvark
18.04 Bionic Beaver
18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish
...
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any release named with A or C for this time. **But** on 17.10 the name is "A". And also the 18.10 with "C" name.

Look here for additional information: [Development Code Name](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames)

Answer (score 0):

The first such release was Warty Warthog (released with "warts and all"), so it was certainly out of order, too, although at that time there really was no system for naming the releases.  The next release was Hoary Hedgehog (staying with the "hog" idea, I guess), and after that came Breezy Badger, and then Dapper Drake.  It appears the alphabetical idea came along with - or right after - Edgy Eft, so the "A" and "C" names weren't used just because the system wasn't yet in place.

Of course, there's also no reason to think that such a naming convention should start with the beginning of the alphabet, anyway, as after Zany Zoophyte it can just wrap around; I guess the alphabet can start wherever one prefers.